# Why am I not able to reassign this basic variables value (GODOT game engine)

Tags: string, variables, null, var, godot

I have a simple variable in an autoload called " var Current_Scene" , it has no value assigned to it ( which means its automatically null.

In my game when you click a button, "Current_Scene"s value is SUPPOSED to change to a string called "Main Street". When I check if the value changed in debug it says "Current_Scenes" value is still null. Even when I experimented by presetting "Current_Scenes" value to the string "cat" , After I tried to change it to "Main Street" , debug said it was STILL cat. Idk what I'm missing?

**below is my code that checks if my value was properly reassigned: (inside of  Scene 2)**

```
func _ready():
        if SceneChange.Current_Scene != "Main Street":
        print(SceneChange.Current_Scene)
```

**below is my code inside of my autoload that sets up the variable: (inside of an Autoload)**

```
var Current_Scene
```

**below is my code for the button that I want to change my variables value: (inside of a different, Scene 1)**

```
func _on_Button_pressed():
#starts world clock when start button is clicked
WorldClock._WorldTimerStart()

SceneChange.RemoveScene()
SceneChange.enter_main_street()
SceneChange.Current_Scene = "Main Street"
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your scene loading code (`RemoveScene`+`enter_main_scene`implementation), so I just used `get_tree().change_scene(...`. I was not able to reproduce the problem this way so maybe it is in your scene loading/changing code. Please provide your implementation of these methods to elaborate further or try to change it to `get_tree().change_scene()` and see if the problem is fixed.

My assumption is that the difference between our cases is that your implementation calls `_ready()` callback on second scene BEFORE `SceneChange.Current_Scene = "Main Street"` line is executed. If I use `get_parent().add_child(secondScene.instance())` instead of `get_tree().change_scene()`, that would be the case for me. To fix that swap the lines of code that do the string assignment and adding packed second scene as a child node of a current one.

My implementation:

```
# Autoload named 'Global'
extends Node

var global_string = "cat"
```

---

```
# Script attached to the root node of "MainStreet.tscn"
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    if Global.global_string != "Main Street":
        print(Global.global_string)
```

---

```
# Script attached to the button on the first scene:
extends Button

func _on_Button_pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene("res://MainStreet.tscn")
    Global.global_string = "Main Street"
```

Fix in case second scene is added with `add_child`:

```
var secondScene = load("res://MainStreet.tscn")

func _on_Button_pressed():
    Global.global_string = "Main Street" # should go first
    get_parent().add_child(secondScene.instance()) # calls _ready() on second scene
```

As [this Godot tutorial](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html) proposes, you could also postpone you scene change with `call_deffered("your_method_that_changes_scene")`.

My Godot version is `3.2.3`.